# Drawing points on a fictional map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, editing

I have a map of a world created in a novel.  It's currently a JPEG.  I imported it into QGIS as a raster layer.  Now I want to add points to it and some data so that I can color code them etc.

I know how to do all this in ArcGIS but my license will expire soon so I'm trying to learn how to redo my map in QGIS.

My specific questions:

1. What do I do in QGIS to be able to add points to the map?  In ArcGIS I would save it as a shapefile and then use the "Editor" function.  I can't seem to find the parallel function in QGIS.
2. So I think this is a 2 step process: 1. Convert the raster image into a shapefile, and 2. open an editor that will allow me to draw points on the map.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking one question per Question. Please [edit] the question to focus on one task.

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/index.html

Comment: Take into consideration that you can't really do what you proposed. Vector data and Raster images are separate things. You have to create a point layer (shapefile) independent of your raster image, draw the features into that shapefile, style the points, and then export your map with the points layered above your original raster image.

Answer (score 6):

In QGIS you go to `Layer > Create Layer > New Shapefile Layer...` From there a dialogue opens where you can specify the type and columns of the new shapefile.

When you right-click on the newly created Layer you can select "Toggle Editing". To add points to the Layer you need to add the "Digitizing Toolbar" in `View > Toolbars > Digitizing Toolbar`. The 4th button lets you "Add Point Feature".

Here are screenshots from QGIS 3.0:

#### "New Shapefile Layer..." in Menu

[image: Screenshot of New Shapefile Layer... highlighted in QGIS 3.0 menu]

#### "New Shapefile Layer" dialogue

[image: Screenshot of New Shapefile Layer dialogue in QGIS 3.0]

#### "Toggle Editing" in context menu

[image: Toggle Editing highlighted in context menu in QGIS 3.0]

#### Digitizing Toolbar in menu

[image: Digitizing Toolbar highlighted in QGIS 3.0 menu]

#### Digitizing Toolbar

[image: Screenshot of Digitizing Toolbar in QGIS 3.0]